# Check if connected to database (right username/password, host)

Tags: php, mysql

I would love to check if i can connect to database using given username, password, and database host.

**So far i was trying:**

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$conndatabase = mysql_select_db($dbname);

if(!mysql_ping($conn) || !$conndatabase){ 
    //do something when cant connect 
} else { 
    //do something when you connected
}
```

It works when i give bad `$dbname`, cuz it cant select this database. But when i give wrong host, username or password, it will give me white page with errors. For example:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'rootx'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\strony\planer\config\opendb.php on line 6
Warning: mysql_ping() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\strony\planer\grupy.php on line 3
```

**Question:**
Is there  a way to check if i can connect using given data without errors? It just gives errors before getting to `mysql_ping()`

**EDIT**
After trying Mike Brant solution, i think i could have explained it wrong. I am trying to connect to database, and if it lets me, it shows user page he wanted to access, but when it's impossible, it redirects him to the other page, to modify database information.

```
if(!$conndatabase){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

I am using that for checking if database exists. But if i try `if(!$conn)` or something similar, its too late, because i got errors displayed on `$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)`. So i cant redirect, as it gives me

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'~~
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by~~
```

Comment: Why don't you just check for errors from `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()`?

Comment: Or, better yet, use mysqli.

Comment: Sure, downwote not saying why. That makes me learn a lot. -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look on my edit in question, you can see those answers didn't solve my problem completely. I still lacked some way to avoid errors. That's where i used `error_reporting(0);`.
I am not sure if that's best solution, but it works like a charm for me.
So the code for everything i tried to achieve looks like that:

**opendb.php file**

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = 'password123';
   $dbname = 'databasename';
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   $conndatabase = mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

And there on the site i am checking connection:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(0);
   include 'opendb.php';
   if(!mysql_ping($conn) || !$conndatabase){
        header('Location: index.php'); //or any other site where you can config your database connection information.
   }
```

So yeah, thats complete solution to my problem. I guess i could use `!$conn` instead of `!mysql_ping($conn)` with same result.

Comment: I would suggest not turning off `error_reporting` while in the process of development.  You need to understand how to handle error messages properly, not just stop logging them. By suppressing them you are going to make your life much more difficult when trying to debug problems. If you simply want to suppress errors to screen, use `ini_set('display_errors', '0')` to suppress them on screen. Don't turn of the error reporting completely. In this way you can still checks logs for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Just test the value of `$conn`.  If it is `false` then the connection failed, and you shouldn't even try to proceed to the db selection step.

Your code might look like this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (false === $conn) {
    throw new Exception('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_select = mysql_select_db($dbname. $conn);
if (false === $db_select) {
    throw new Exception('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error($conn));
}
```

The PHP documentation is very clear on this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

By the way, you should look at using `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: everyone talking about switching to mysqli or PDO, but when this project started, it wasn't deprecated yet, and changing every mysql function now, seems like bad idea. Or at least lots of work.

Comment: @Kedor Actually if you have have a well designed DB abstraction, changing out would be rather easy.  Also, if you use mysqli you would have almost a one-for-one swap function mapping so moving from mysql to procedural mysqli, is almost a find/replace exercise.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not something i meant. (i mean your answer). It still gives me error trying to `mysql_connect`. I am trying to redirect to other page, if user/password/host is wrong. And if i try it with this solution, it says headers were already sent. Errors were already written on the page. See update of my question

Comment: @Kedor Then just make sure your exceptions (if you used those) are caught and handled such that you don't have any output to the browser. This will let you use `header()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug your connection with something like

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

In this way you can easilly check if connection is estabilished otherwise you will print an error.

Then I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Well, it works, it will give me message saying i "Could not connect:~~", but it also gives me php error before that. Which is something i want to avoid.

Comment: @Kedor what php error do you get? About mysql error hou have mistakes in your credentials

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, it’s the first example on the PHP manual page for the [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) function.

Secondly, you should be either using the [`mysqli_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), as the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and currently being phased out.

To check a connection with PDO:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'pass');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```